# How exactly is a pointer to statically allocated structure, returned from a function?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, time

In Michael Kerrisk's book, I came across to such statements as below:

> - "The gmtime() and localtime() functions convert a time_t value into a
>   so-called broken- down time. The broken-down time is placed in a
>   statically allocated structure whose address is returned as the
>   function result.

```
  #include <time.h> 
  struct tm *gmtime(const time_t timep );
  struct tm *localtime(const time_t * timep ); 
  /* Both return a pointer to a statically allocated broken-down time structure on
 success, or NULL on error */
```

So I tried to figure out what exaclty was meant by saying "pointer to statically allocated structure" and when traced the source code for *"time.h"* file,and I reached the file *glibc/time/localtime.c* when tracking the source in order as below;
https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/time/gmtime.c.html

https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/time/localtime.c.html#22

and as far as I understand **gmtime()** function returns a pointer to this globally defined structure as declared below:

```
struct tm _tmbuf;
```

So my question, did I get correct till so far, that the gmtime returns just a pointer to this global structure? If it is so, next question, is it possible I could define globals inside my shared library files let's say? And if yes, how could one access those globals inside library files?

Comment: Yes, you got it correct. However, your follow-up isn't clear. Yes, you can have global variables in shared libraries and access it like any other global variable. What's the difficult to understand?

Comment: "pointer to statically allocated structure" for example `Person p = Person_create("John", 35, "Canada"); Person *pp = &p` so here the variable `pp` is a pointer to a statically allocated structure

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you've got it correct, and yes, you can do the same thing.  If you were going to write a function like this in your own library, it could look like this:

```
struct tm _tmbuf;

struct tm *gmtime(const time_t *timep)
{
    struct tm *t = &_tmbuf;
    // Do some things with timep and t.
    return t;
}
```

Note, however, that as written, this is not thread safe.  If you want people to use your library in a threaded program, you'll need to [declare your variable as thread local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage); use a mutex, rwlock, or other mutual exclusion mechanism; or provide a thread-safe version like `localtime_r` or `gmtime_r` where the user specifies the structure to use as the output.

For these reasons, it's generally considered undesirable to do this, and languages like Rust make it hard because it's easy for it to be thread unsafe.

Comment: So would it be portable when use **_Thread_local** or **thread_local** for variable declarations?

Comment: It's not that it's not portable, it's just that it's not thread safe.  You can use either of those C11 thread local declarations or the one provided by your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. In the example a char[] array is used, but you could do this with structures, too

static.c:

```
#include <string.h>

static char my_name[] = __FILE__;

char * get_name(void)
{
return my_name;
}


void set_name(char *newname)
{
size_t len;
if (!newname) return;

len = strlen(newname);
if (len >= sizeof my_name) len =  sizeof my_name -1;

memcpy(my_name, newname, len);
my_name[len] = 0;
}
```

static.h:

```
extern char * get_name(void) ;
extern void set_name(char *newname) ;
```

staticmain.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "static.h"

int main(void)
{
char *name;

name = get_name();
printf("Name=%s\n", name);

set_name( "OMG!");

name = get_name();
printf("Name=%s\n", name);

return 0;
}
```

Compile and link them:

```
$ cc -Wall staticmain.c static.c
```

Run it:

```
$ ./a.out
Name=static.c
Name=OMG!
$
```

---

In your case you would put the static.o object into a (shared) library, but the mechanism is the same